# Increment button using map method in react

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, increment

Below code of incrementing the button. But am facing the issue in the increment function to increment the value.

```
const [items, setItems] = useState([
        {itemName:'item1', quantity:2, isSelected:false},
        {itemName:'item2', quantity:5, isSelected:false},
        {itemName:'item3', quantity:7, isSelected:false}
    ]);

    const increment = (index) => {
        setItems([...items, 
            index.quantity++
        ])  }

<button onClick={() => increment(index)}>increment</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are adding an item to the items array instead of editing the desired item, remember that you should also treat state immutably:

```
const increment = (index) => {
  setItems((items) => {
    const prevItem = items[index];
    return Object.assign([], items, {
      [index]: { ...prevItem, quantity: prevItem.quantity + 1 },
    });
  });
};
```